# Cómo escribir la cadena \f en un string en python

Tags: python, string

tengo un string en Python en formato LaTex como el siguiente:

```
string_A = '$$R=\frac{A}{P}$$'
```

sin embargo Python detecta la cadena `\f` como lo que se conoce como Escape Sequence, he intentado separar el string de la siguiente manera `'\'+'f'`, pero `'\'` también se reconoce como un escape sequence así que la situación es la misma, espero me haya explicado bien.

Comment: Usa doble barra `\\\`

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que "escapar" la barra con otra barra:

```
string_A = '$$R=\\frac{A}{P}$$'
```